# ktlint and KotlinProjectExtension

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, ktlint

I tried to implement Kotlin check style in project using ktlint.
I added

```
plugins {
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "10.1.0" apply false
}
```

in root *build.gradle.kts* and

```
plugins {
id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")
}
```

in *build.gradle.kts* in subprojects

When I called

> gradlew ktlintCheck

I got

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* What went wrong:
org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/dsl/KotlinProjectExtension
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this really the only line or are there more details to what failed exactly? My first guess would be, that it would be fine if you run it from the subprojects. can you run `gradlew projects` and the use `ktlintCheck` for one of the subprojects?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately exactly the only line

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding 
```buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle:10.1.0")
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply(plugin = "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")```
in project's build.gradle

Comment: and 
```subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") // Version should be inherited from parent
    repositories {
        // Required to download KtLint
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Optionally configure plugin
    configure<org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.KtlintExtension> {
        debug.set(true)
    }```
to subproject's build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

This is how I went about it for **Klint with Kotlin DSL** on `gradle.kts` files for Android Gradle. Have also added **Spotless with Kotlin DSL** ( code formatter ) at the same time.

It is also worth noting mine is **NOT** a Multi Module project.

**Step 1 - gradle.kts (app)** - Add Klint and Spotless plugins and import `Reporters`

```
import org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.reporter.ReporterType

plugins {
            id("com.android.application") ... 
            //Klint
            id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "11.0.0"

            //Spotless
            id("com.diffplug.spotless")
        }
```

**Step 2 - gradle.kts (app)** - Configure *Klint only*

```
// ktlintFormat task will need to run before preBuild
tasks.getByPath("preBuild")
    .dependsOn("ktlintFormat")

configure<org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.KtlintExtension> {

    android.set(true)
    ignoreFailures.set(false)
    disabledRules.set(setOf("final-newline", "no-wildcard-imports"))
    reporters {
        reporter(ReporterType.PLAIN)
        reporter(ReporterType.CHECKSTYLE)
        reporter(ReporterType.SARIF)
    }
}
```

**Step 3 - gradle.kts(app)** - Configure *Spotless only*

```
configure<com.diffplug.gradle.spotless.SpotlessExtension> {
    kotlin {
        // version, setUseExperimental, userData and editorConfigOverride are all optional
        ktlint("0.45.2")
            .setUseExperimental(true)
            .userData(mapOf("android" to "true"))
            .editorConfigOverride(mapOf("indent_size" to 2))
    }
    kotlinGradle {
        target("*.gradle.kts") // default target for kotlinGradle
        ktlint() // or ktfmt() or prettier()
    }
}
```

**Step 4 - gradle.kts(project)** - Add *Spotless* in the Classpath

```
buildscript {

    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        
        ... 
        //class path for Spotless
        classpath("com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:6.9.1")
    }

}
```

The 2 plugins works fine with this set-up.